# Is there a way to list cloud storage descending IOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

in the firebase documentation there is a `list` function for cloud storage for IOS, but what I'm trying to do is paginate and get the results in a descending order like how firestore does (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?hl=en&authuser=2#order_and_limit_data).

Does anyone know how to do that if it's possible?

I tried looking through documentation and looking online if any one has been able to use list with order(by: "", descending: true).limit(50) but have found nothing.

The reason why I think it should be possible is because apparently when you create a cloud storage in firebase it creates a version of firestore you don't see and is handled by cloud storage. So its really I'm curious if anyone else has been able to do something similar.

Comment: Answer for the Storage API is below, but I couldn't make sense of the last paragraph of your question. If that is still relevant even after reading my answer below, you might want to edit your question (there's a link right under it) to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Results for the Cloud Storage list APIs are always returned in ascending lexicographical order. If you need them in a different order, you will have to reorder them in your application code.

Comment: But what if you have hundreds of thousands of files how can you get them and put them into a different order pretty sure that won’t scale well ?

Comment: You're reading data from the network, and then reordering it in local memory. If you're reading a lot of files, the performance problem is going to be in retrieving it from the network, not in that local reordering.